# Get version history of each file in document set

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-set, version-history

Can anyone help me to get version history of each file in document set.
I have tried as below. here im able to get file name in doc set.

```
                  SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
                  SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

                  string ver = web.Url + "/" + sharedDocs;


                  //Get the selected document
                  SPListItem listItem = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Contract Documents"].GetItemById(99);
       if (listItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
          //Get the folder 
          SPFolder myFolder = listItem.Folder;

          //Make sure the folder has items
          if (myFolder.ItemCount > 0)
          {
            //For each item get the document name
            foreach (SPFile item in myFolder.Files)
            { 
              string name = item.Name;
              foreach (SPListItem vh in myFolder.Files)
              {
                 SPListItemVersionCollection coll = vh.Versions;
                 foreach (SPListItemVersion version in coll)
                 {
                     var VersionLabel =version.VersionLabel;


                 }
              }
            }
```

i'm using sharepoint server 2013.

Please suggest me how to retrieve version history from document set. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this.. Its works fine . But still i didn't get current version of the file. Means I have a file with versions 1.0, 1.1.
but it showing count=1 and showing previous one. 1.0

```
 SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
      SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

    //Get the selected document
    SPListItem listItem = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Contract Documents"].GetItemById(99);

    if (listItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
    {
      //Get the folder 
      SPFolder myFolder = listItem.Folder;

      //Make sure the folder has items
      if (myFolder.ItemCount > 0)
      {
        //For each item get the document name
        foreach (SPFile item in myFolder.Files)
        { 
          string name = item.Name;
          SPFileVersionCollection filecollection = item.Versions;
          if (filecollection.Count > 0)
             {
               foreach (SPFileVersion v in filecollection)
               {
                  var VersionLabel =v.VersionLabel;
               }

          }
        }
```

}
}